# Tense agreement in a somehow complicated case

Tags: tense-agreement

This is my sentence:

> 1) In his letter, written between the 22nd and 28th of October 1885, I. D. Wilson mentioned Mrs. Beard who had promised to take care of the old Mrs. Wilson **if she came** to enjoy with her son that wonderful creation of the young architect.
>
> 2) ... if she would come ...
>
> 3) ... had she come / if she had come ...

I am not sure especially about that "if she came". I do not know if it is the right choice. I have thought of two other alternatives (2 and 3) but I am also unsure about them.

What is the right form of the sentence?

Comment: or **should she come** / **if she should come**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with her son" ... "come with her son to enjoy" or "come to enjoy with her son".  Is she accompanying her son on  a trip or meeting her son where he is?

Comment: 1) Come together with her son by train. I. D. Wilson and his mother were invited to come together by train and admire a new building. The mother was old and Mrs. Beard who lived close to that new building had promised to take care of Mrs. Wilson for a few days. 2) Does "should" work well with "if"? If I have no other answer I will select "should she come".

Comment: Either will do: *should she come with her son to enjoy* or *if she should come with her son to enjoy*. Modal **should** there expresses possibility and is thus not anchored to a particular tense.  **if she came** is not incorrect by any means, but **should** works better with your style, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

What did Mrs. Beard say?

- If she said "I promise to take care of Mrs. Wilson if she and her son come  ...", you want

  > ... had promised to take care of old Mrs. Wilson if she and her son came ...
- If she said "I promise to take care of Mrs. Wilson if she and her son will come ...", you want

  > ... had promised to take care of old Mrs. Wilson if she and her son would come ...

An indicative *promise* has subsequent reference, as both of these do (the *will* in the second version adds a 'volitive' sense, that Mrs. Wilson and her son are willing to come), and ordinarily its condition does, too: it's hard to imagine Mrs. Wilson saying "I promise to take care of her if she has come", making the promise contingent on a prior event, except in the unusual case where it was unclear whether or not Mrs. Wilson had come.

Consequently it's very unlikely that a conditional would take the form *if she ... had come*.

Comment: I do not know exactly what Mrs. Beard said but it was likely: "I promise to take care of Mrs. Wilson if she and her son come". What I know for sure is that Mrs. Wilson never came. I. D. Wilson visited that building alone.